# Facebook like button and post to wall not display title, description, image

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have created a new page on my site, http://www.example.com/123456 (as its not an issue for 1-2 days old pages).

I have set up the meta tags correctly:

```
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="123456789" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description here ..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/images/123456.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Example" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of page" />
<meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/123456" />
```

When click on like button, not displaying title, description and image, it just displays the url of the page.

When i visit debugger tool http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and enter my page url, its getting correct Object Properties, Raw Open Graph Document Information and URLs. One warning Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed - Extraneous Property:   Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'fb:page_id'.

But when i visit the page again (http://www.example.com/123456), clicked on facebook like button, can see tile, description, image and url. (fb:page_id warning is not effecting)

Questions:

1. Is that means facebook itself will not cache the data, you need to force it every time?
2. If yes, how this is working for old pages (pages have been created 1-2 days ago and liked by some people).
3. Is there any method in facebook, similar to google indexing as we use for sitemap in robots.txt

   Sitemap: http://www.example.com/googlenews.xml

FYI- i can see facebookexternalhit/1.0  and facebookexternalhit/1.1 is hitting my site, that means facebook is fetching data.
The new pages i am creating are not password protected via htaccess or IP restrictions,.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `fb:admins` or `fb:app_id` should be used, and not `fb:page_id`.  Reference: [Insights](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/)

Comment: If it's a new page, then FB has to scrape it before the title, description, and image can appear. The scrape is generally done when the object is liked, or an OG action is published, or it is entered into the Debugger.

Comment: Thanks Donn.
Can you please guide how we can publish an OG action?

Comment: Yes, I'll post a screenshot later today

Comment: To create a sample action, go to the FB App Dashboard, Open Graph settings. Click "Get Code" link that is next to your action.  Then copy-paste the `curl` command in the section "Create a new X action".  The following screenshot shows the `curl` command to publish a sample `cook` action on a `recipe` object:

[Screenshot: publish sample action dialog](http://i.imgur.com/GdlP6.png)

Comment: Thanks Donn,
I do have another question actually re: adding our Like button to the open graph. Currently we have action (like) but we have not submitted it. It seems if we were to do this, a user who accepts the action (like) would then have all articles they viewed on our website shared into their news stream automatically. Is that correct?

Comment: I would not worry about that. I don't think that would happen and even if it did, Facebook has filters and aggregation to prevent newsfeed from looking spammy.